# if else statement is failing in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a very simple shell script which is failing at if-else. And I am not able to understand what is wrong. I checked my syntax and indentation.

```
echo_usr()
{
    read -p "Do you want to preserve $EIP_HOME/conf and $EIP_HOME/installer/.datastore? [Y/N] " usr_in

    kill_java()

    if [ "$usr_in" == "y*" ] || [ "$usr_in" == "Y*" ]; then
        preserve_conf()
    else
        if [ "$usr_in" == "n*" ] || [ "$usr_in" == "N*" ]; then
            reset_home_eip()
        else
            echo "Invalid input"
        fi
    fi

    reset_db()
}
```

It is giving me the following error:
    syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Comment: I've updated my answer to address another problem in your function.

Answer (score 6):

To call a function with no arguments, just use the name of the function. Empty parentheses are not necessary, and in fact are a syntax error. (Or, more precisely, it's part of the syntax for a function *definition*, and if you try to use it as a function call you'll get a syntax error message later -- if you're lucky.)

The idea is that a call to a shell function looks and acts like an invocation of an external program.

For example, change:

```
preserve_conf()
```

to

```
preserve_conf
```

(Using `elif` rather than `else` followed by `if` is a good idea, but it's not the cause of the problem you're seeing.)

There's another problem that you won't see until you get past the syntax error (thanks to Sam for pointing it out in a comment). This:

```
if [ "$usr_in" == "y*" ] || [ "$usr_in" == "Y*" ]; then
```

isn't going to work correctly; the `==` operator used by the `[` / `test` built-in doesn't do wildcard matching.  If you're using bash, you can use `[[` rather than `[`, and you can also combine the `y` and `Y` cases into a single pattern:

```
if [[ "$usr_in" == [yY]* ]] ; then
    ...
elif [[ "$usr_in" == [nN]* ]] ; then
    ...
fi
```

If you don't have a shell that supports that syntax, a `case` statement might be your next best bet -- in fact that's probably even cleaner than the `if` version:

```
case "$usr_in" in
    [yY]*)
        ...
        ;;
    [nN]*)
        ...
        ;;
    *)
        ...
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: To add to this: a function definition doesn't need to start with curly braces; it just needs a compound statement. Since `if` is a compound statement, your call to `kill_java` actually starts a new function definition. The "call" to `preserve_conf` is followed by `else`, which is not (the beginning of) a compound statement, and so you finally get a syntax error.

Comment: So technically, calling a function with empty parentheses isn't a syntax error, but it *is* the syntax for defining a function, so the code that follows it will likely cause a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I updated the code for function call which is mentioned here but I missed on `elif`. Thanks.

Comment: the comments above are correct. But I'm just wondering what shell are you using that you can match wildcards in == comparison? It's no sh, bash, zsh or ksh. Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: @Sam: Good catch. Probably the OP hadn't noticed that problem yet, because the script was dying due to the syntax error.